# Get xmlpath without closing tag

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping, for-xml-path

I need to get the 'value' here, but I think it's failing as there is no closing tag:

```
<input id="knowledge-currency__tgt-input" class="vk_gy vk_sh IxBI8c" value="5641.10" aria-label="Currency Amount Field" type="number" jsaction="input:fire.cc_input_value_change" data-ved="0ahUKEwiklK6Nh7faAhXqAcAKHW5wDiAQwKsBCCowAA">
```

This is the code I'm using so far (in an online xmlpath checker it only works if I add a closing tag manually):

```
//input[@id='knowledge-currency__tgt-input']/@value
```

Comment: `input` is an HTML tag and it shouldn't contain closing tag! XPath should handle this case correctly. Don't test it in some specific XMLpath tester - just try in real code

Comment: I'm using google sheets, but just getting '#N/A' - this is the cell contents: 
=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/finance?q=BTCGBP","//input[@id='knowledge-currency__tgt-input']/@value")

Comment: Code works fine when I test it: http://jsbin.com/muyihotegi/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Is there any namespace involved?